# How to loop through a list of strings with SQL SEVER stored procedure and update a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to loop through a list of email addresss with a SQL stored procedure
-Get the first part of the email addresses and query another table where the part matches a a field

```
DECLARE @channelName char(100)
DECLARE @EmailAddress char(100)
DECLARE @ParsedEmailID char(100)

DECLARE gpluscursor  CURSOR for Select email from Accounts
OPEN gpluscursor 
Fetch NEXT from gpluscursor
into @EmailAddress
While @@Fetch_Status=0
Begin
 While @EmailAddress is not NULL
  Begin
  PRINT @EmailAddress
    set @ParsedEmailID = (SELECT  SUBSTRING(email,0,CHARINDEX('-',email)) from Accounts where email = @EmailAddress)
    PRINT @ParsedEmailID
    set @channelName = (SELECT channelname FROM channel where channelname like '%'+@ParsedEmailID+'%')
    PRINT 'mychannel'+@channelName
    update Accounts set channel = @channelName where email like @EmailAddress
  End
 Fetch Next from gpluscursor
 into @EmailAddress
  PRINT @EmailAddress
End
close gpluscursor
```

Here is the result from the output:

```
test-9724@pages.plusgoogle.com                                                           
test                                                                                     

test-9724@pages.plusgoogle.com                                                           
test                                                                                     

test-9724@pages.plusgoogle.com                                                           
test
```

It appears that the cursor is not moving to the next record . What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: This can be achieved without using a cursor, do you have a specific reason to use one?

Comment: I would rather not use a cursor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT channelName,SUBSTRING(email,0,CHARINDEX('-',email))
from Accounts as A 
INNER JOIN channel AS c ON channelname like SUBSTRING(email,0,CHARINDEX('-',email))
```

Isnt the most efficient but it will get you there. It would be better if we could remove the like comparison but if thats what you have that is what we will use.

Answer (score 0):

As far as your Cursor is concerned, Change your `WHILE` to an `IF`. Your code is getting into an infinite loop...

But as others have mentioned, a more optimized approach would be to not use a `Cursor`

```
DECLARE @channelName char(100)
DECLARE @EmailAddress char(100)
DECLARE @ParsedEmailID char(100)

DECLARE gpluscursor  CURSOR for Select email from Accounts
OPEN gpluscursor 
Fetch NEXT from gpluscursor
into @EmailAddress
While @@Fetch_Status=0
Begin
 IF (@EmailAddress is not NULL)
  Begin
  PRINT @EmailAddress
    set @ParsedEmailID = (SELECT  SUBSTRING(email,0,CHARINDEX('-',email)) from Accounts where email = @EmailAddress)
    PRINT @ParsedEmailID
    set @channelName = (SELECT channelname FROM channel where channelname like '%'+@ParsedEmailID+'%')
    PRINT 'mychannel'+@channelName
    update Accounts set channel = @channelName where email like @EmailAddress
  End
 Fetch Next from gpluscursor
 into @EmailAddress
  PRINT @EmailAddress
End
close gpluscursor
```

Comment: sometimes answering the question isn't the right thing to do. In instances like these if you see OP doing something the wrong way, sometimes it is better to suggest a better way of doing it instead of fixing OP's issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think your variable type, char, might be part of your issue.

Run this:

```
DECLARE @ParsedEmailID char(100)
SELECT @ParsedEmailID = 'test'
PRINT '%' + @ParsedEmailID + '%'
```

What is the output? It is this (scroll to the right to see the end %):

```
%test                                                                                                %
```

Probably not what you wanted. Switch char to varchar:

```
DECLARE @ParsedEmailID varchar(100)
SELECT @ParsedEmailID = 'test'
PRINT '%' + @ParsedEmailID + '%'
```

Now, what is the output? It is this:

```
%test%
```

I suspect that this is what you were going for.